# How do I run a Bash script using crontab on startup? Other solutions haven't worked

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, cron

I'm trying run a bash script when my machine boots up using crontab that will open a terminal and then open btop, a command-line tool, in that terminal. The bash script I've written is in a file named startm and the contents are below:

```
#!/bin/bash
    gnome-terminal --command="bash -c 'btop; $SHELL'"
```

It opens a terminal, then runs the btop command in that terminal. The `$SHELL` bit is just to keep the terminal window open when the script has finished running.

In my crontab as a superuser I input the following:

```
@reboot /home/username/Scripts/startm
```

The script is already executable. If anyone has any ideas about what I'm doing wrong, or other ways I can accomplish this, please respond. I am new to Linux & Bash and any guidance will be appreciated.

Comment: `man 5 crontab`: "Please note that startup, as far as @reboot is concerned, is  the  time when  the cron(8) daemon startup.  In particular, it may be before some system daemons, or other facilities, were startup." What makes you think the graphical environment is even available when your script runs?

Comment: If you are using gnome, add it to the session autostart. eg.https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/XDG_Autostart

Comment: *"Other solutions haven't worked"* - well obviously, that depends on what it was you tried.  Telling us that something didn't work isn't helpful if you don't say what it was.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, the problem is that you can't run gnome-terminal until there is a gnome desktop to run it on, and there won't be a desktop until you have logged in.  Doing it from crontab is not going to work.

One way to do this is to put something into your ~/.bash-login script or similar to run the script when you login.